# Comparing irrational powers

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I want to compare  two numbers of the form $a^b$ and $b^a$ for $a,b, >1$.
The simpler way that I know is to start from:
$$
a^b\le b^a \quad \iff \quad b\log a\le a \log b \quad \iff \quad \frac{b}{\log b} \le \frac{a}{\log a}
$$
and, studying the function:
$$
y= \frac{x}{\log x}
$$
we see that it has a minimum for $x=e$ (the graph is in the figure).

[image]

So we have 
$$
1<a<b<e \Rightarrow \frac{b}{\log b}<\frac{a}{\log a} \Rightarrow a^b<b^a
$$
and
$$
e<a<b \Rightarrow \frac{b}{\log b}>\frac{a}{\log a} \Rightarrow a^b>b^a
$$

But I don't see a simple solution for the case $1<a<e<b$ as for

$$
(\sqrt{6})^{\sqrt{8}} \le (\sqrt{8})^{\sqrt{6}}
$$

In this case we are forced to calculate the values of the two exponentials? Or is there some other way to make the comparison, such that we can verify an inequality as
$$
\left( \sqrt[2n]{a^n-1}\right)^{\sqrt[2n]{b^n-1} } \le \left( \sqrt[2n]{b^n-1}\right)^{\sqrt[2n]{a^n-1} }
$$
also for great values of $n$?

Comment: In the beginning of your reasoning, there is a mistake: you divide by $\log(a)$ while you don't know the sign of it. You should distinguish $a>1$ and $a<1$, similarly for $b$

Comment: One could expand the Taylor series of $\log x / x$ about $x = e$ and use Taylor estimates. Since $|e - \sqrt{6}|, |e - \sqrt{8}| < \frac{1}{3}$, one shouldn't need an outrageous number of terms, but note that the values of the function at $\sqrt{6}$ and $\sqrt{8}$ differ by only $1$ part in $~200$, so this calculation is a bit delicate...

Comment: @JohnSteinbeck.  Thank you. I see, But  really I use only $a,b >1$ . I fix..